# Remove Item from DataProvider causing ERROR 1009

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, runtime-error, dataprovider, flash-builder4.5

This is a view-based project for Android using Flash Builder 4.5

In my `views.ListView` I have a list element like this 
`<s:List id = "myList" itemRenderer="components.myCustomRenderer" dataProvider="{Global.itemArrayList}"> </s:List>`

`Global` is a class I use to store shared values for all the views

`myCustomRenderer` list has a `deleteButton` which when clicked, execute the following **function**

```
public function deleteButtonnHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var removeItem:myItem = super.data as myItem;
        this.parentApplication.navigator.activeView.myList.dataProvider.removeItem(removeItem);
    }
```

it also overrides the set data function as follow

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void {
        super.data = value;
        nameText.text = value.name;
    }
```

when I click the deleteButton, I get ERROR #1009 saying the line `nameText.text = value.name` accesses properties of null object

I try removing the item from `Global.itemArrayList` directly but the same error occurs. This is my first time dealing with custom ItemRenderer and List so I don't understand the events that are dispatched when an item is removed very well. Tracing the error message, I see some kind of dataProvider change event was dispatched but as to why that causes the error I have no clue.

Other than this error, my renderer and list work fine.

Some help to elucidate me on the subject and to solve this problem would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update setter `data` in following way, you should avoid error 1009:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void {
    super.data = value;
    if (value) {
        nameText.text = value.name;
    } else {
        nameText.text = "";
    }       
}
```

Comment: thanks very much that's much simpler than I thought. I guess I was caught up with the question why the setter is still called even though the dataProvider is empty

Comment: It might be caused by the fact, that you're invoking remove action directly from renderer.